# Retrieve subcategory selection option via Ajax based on category selection

Tags: php, ajax

like title says, I'm trying to populate one selection element based from selection of another.

I've come up with this code, which works when I'm retrieving records from db with live search but something is not firing here, so help would be appreciated:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    function search() {
        var query_value = $('select#category_id').val();

        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_php/subcategory.php",
                data: { category: query_value},
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("select#subcateogry").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

});
```

PHP code in short, I'm catching post variable, doing query and echoing:

```
echo "<option value='".$result['id']."'>".$result['subcategory']."</option>";
```

HTML:

```
<p>
    <label>Item Subcategory:</label>
    <select id='subcategory' name='subcategory'>

    </select>
</p>
```

Is there any obvious mistake that I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: What is `select#subcateogry`? Is this JavaScript/jQuery function properly called? Try putting an alert box in the `success` handler to see, if it is invoked properly and you get the desired AJAX response.

Comment: It is just a select element into which I need to embed selection options which are retrieved from db

Answer (score 0):

You can call the ajax method on the onchange event of the category section
I have made some changes in the code please have a look into it 
    success:functon(data)//html

```
$('select#category_id').onChange(function(){
  search();
}); 


function search() {
    var query_value = $('select#category_id').val();
    if(query_value !== ''){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_php/subcategory.php",
            data: { category: query_value},
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("select#subcateogry").html(data);
            }
        });
    }return false;    
}
```